# Finding a Compatible Basis of $\mathbb{Z}^4$ and a subgroup

Tags: group-theory

I am self-studying group theory and came along this question and am stuck:

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^4$ generated by $(-1,-2,-3,-4), (3,8,5,6), (-1,0,-13,-16), (-3,-4,-13,-6).$ Find a compatible basis of $\mathbb{Z}^4$ and $H$ as well as its rank and invariant factors.  Sorry if this is an overly simple question but is this just a matter of treating these generating sets as vectors and forming a matrix to obtain the basis the traditional method or is there something I am missing?
[image: I have attached an image of the definition for basis given in my textbook]

Comment: what is definition of Z^4?

Comment: And, what is a compatible basis? I searched the term on google and I can't find any hits. Do you just mean basis in the regular sense?

Comment: Are you sure these are groups and not vector spaces? I've never seen the concept of basis of a group (only of vector spaces or modules)

Comment: I believe the term basis in this context would refer to the set of generators for the group. I am attaching a definition given in the textbook I am using to my original post. @Marcos

Comment: Yes, you form a matrix with the vectors. But you are working over the integers, not a field. You need to put the matrix into *Smith Normal Form* using unimodular row and column operations.

Comment: @Buraian A compatible basis of ${\mathbb Z}^4$ is a free basis $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$ such that $H$ has a free basis of the form $\lambda_1b_1, \lambda_2b_2,\lambda_3b_3,\lambda_4b_4$, for integers $\lambda_i \ge 0$ with $\lambda_i|\lambda_{i+1}$. The Smith Normal Form algorithm computes all of this.

Comment: @Marcos An abelian group can be regarded as a ${\mathbb Z}$-module, and so you can talk about a basis. In particular free abelian groups have bases.

Comment: @DerekHolt Right, sorry for the stupid question... thanks for your answer.